# iOS app icon not showing up when searching Google

Tags: ios, iphone, metadata, meta-tags, google-search

We have a sneaker marketplace app and when people type in "sneaker marketplace" on the iPhone, our app shows up along 2 other apps. The icon is missing though (we're the first app below).

How do I tell Google which icon to use? Where does google get this information from? Why isn't my icon showing up?

[image: Google search]

[image]

Comment: Searching Google in an emulator for "Photoshop app" has the same problem for certain apps. Trying to figure it out.

Comment: @sheeptest Ya... it's weird. Seems like they're scraping from the App Store and Google Play, but then they should always get the icon. I thought for a moment that they would only show the icon if you where only on Google Play as well, but the second sneaker app is not.

Comment: Probably just a bug. I searched with my Mac and saw the icon, searched with iPhone and none of the 3 appear...

Comment: @LinusG. When searching with your iPhone, you have to scroll down a little bit to find it.

Answer (score 1):

If Chrome's app and Twitter's app are having this issue, then I would guess that it's not your fault.

I couldn't find a pattern among other apps that have this bug in Google's Mobile Search (Ratings on App Store, Image resolution, description content, etc) that might break whatever is scraping your app icon from the App Store.

It might be a combination of things.

[image]